Can 101.6x101.6x6.35 aluminium square tube hold a lean to roof aluminium will be bolted between two 200x50mm timbers
200x50mm timber joists (c26)
101.6x101.6x6.35 aluminium tube @3.6m
Bolted in between joists and concreatted in the ground by 600mm

This would need a lot more info to be answered. Like what alloy of aluminim, tube thickness, orientation and loading conditions to be answered. But really ask your structural engineer because it sounds like something people get paid to calculate.
